# how to open a specific UserInterface, onClicking on firebase push notification in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, firebase-notifications

- I am using firebase push notification and also my android device get notification too.
  if I get notification, while app is open  and I can read "title" and "Message" and it take me to "UserDetailsActivity" a specific class  .But I also want to  do the same thin on click the the notification. But when click on the notification it doesn't open the "UserDetailsActivity" and it open launchering clas and i can't read the message . Any one have solution for it?
- firebaseService class

  public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
  private static int count = 0;
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

  ```
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDetailsActivity.class));
  ```

  /*
  Message data payload:
  Message Notification Body:
  */

  ```
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }

    }
  ```

  }

*androidMainfest

```
<service
    android:name=".backgroundService.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On launcher activer

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, when messages with both notification and data payload are received and application is in background mode, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of launcher Activity.
Option 1:
You can try to to handle the data in launch activity and from there launch UserDetailsActivity and finish launcher activity quickly without showing UI.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Option 2:
Dont send notification part from FCM and send only payload part. In onmessagereceived() method  ,construct the notification with  pending intent for UserDetails activity or service.

Comment: I tryied to call it in another service but it does n't work

Comment: startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirebaseMessagingService.class));

Comment: You should not use start the firebase message service. You have to get the data in launcher activity and then start the user details activity. Or use only payload data and construct notification with pending intent.

Comment: I dont know how to handle data without firebaseService in launcher class

Comment: are you getting data in launcher activity when you use if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {} . You can pass this data to details activity and finish launcher activity or construct the details UI in launcher activity itself based on the data you receive. If you are not receiving data in launcher then there could be some other issue.